# Change the Chrome App IndexedDB file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, indexeddb

I'm trying to replace the file containing the IndexedDB database of my Chrome App with the database from my client's Chrome App so that I can view and get his data.

I've experimented with installing 2 Chrome Apps on my Google Chrome. I've tried to get the database files from

> C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3\Storage\ext[chrome_app_id]\def\IndexedDB\chrome-extension_[chrome_app_id]_0.indexeddb.leveldb

folder (1st chrome app) and replace the database files on the second one. But the 2nd chrome app's data is still not updated with the data from the 1st one.

Is there a right way to do this?

Comment: To clarify, did you do the replacement while Chrome is fully shut down? Have you tried it between two profiles with the same app ID?

Comment: I successfully updated the database of my chrome app by replacing the database files while chrome is shut down. Thanks @Xan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully updated the indexeddb database of my chrome app by replacing the database files while chrome is shut down.